# Reload a layout in android, update circle progress bar programmatically

Tags: android, android-layout, view

I'm using this library from GitHub: https://github.com/lzyzsd/CircleProgress

I put ArcProgress into my MainLayout. I'm trying to change values on the progress bar but I cannot not see on screen. If I check with `mArcProgress.getProgress();` this get me the right value, but the bar is empty in screen and doesn't show any progress.

I was trying using:

```
mArcProgress.invalidate();
```

but doesnt work.

The only way I found was with:

```
finish();
startActivity(getIntent());
```

but works not as I expected, because the full screen start and seems like a blink.

Anyone know how from another activity, changes this View and make possible to see the changes when setting  `mArcProgress.setProgress(aNumber);`  ?

this is ArcProgressFuel

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.TypedArray;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Path;
import android.graphics.RectF;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Parcelable;

import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class ArcProgressFuel extends View {
    private Paint paint;

    private RectF rectF = new RectF();

    private float strokeWidth;

    public int progress;
    private int max;
    private int finishedStrokeColor;
    private int unfinishedStrokeColor;
    private float arcAngle;

    Path path;

    MainPageFragment mMainPageFragment;

    public static int fuel_to_show;
    private float arcBottomHeight;

    private final int default_finished_color = Color.WHITE;
    private final int default_unfinished_color = Color.rgb(72, 106, 176);

    private final float default_suffix_padding;
    private final float default_stroke_width;
    private final int default_max = 100;
    private final float default_arc_angle = 360 * 0.5f; //0.8 for speed, 0.5 for fuel
    private float default_text_size;
    private final int min_size;

    private static final String INSTANCE_STATE = "saved_instance";
    private static final String INSTANCE_STROKE_WIDTH = "stroke_width";

    public static  String instance_progress = "progress";
    private static final String INSTANCE_MAX = "max";
    private static final String INSTANCE_FINISHED_STROKE_COLOR = "finished_stroke_color";
    private static final String INSTANCE_UNFINISHED_STROKE_COLOR = "unfinished_stroke_color";
    private static final String INSTANCE_ARC_ANGLE = "arc_angle";
    private static final String INSTANCE_SUFFIX = "suffix";


    public ArcProgressFuel(Context context) {
        this(context, null);
    }

    public ArcProgressFuel(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs, 0);
    }

    public ArcProgressFuel(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);

        min_size = (int) Utils.dp2px(getResources(), 100);
        default_suffix_padding = Utils.dp2px(getResources(), 4);
        default_stroke_width = Utils.dp2px(getResources(), 4);

        TypedArray attributes = context.getTheme().obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.ArcProgress, defStyleAttr, 0);
        initByAttributes(attributes);
        attributes.recycle();

        initPainters();
    }

    protected void initByAttributes(TypedArray attributes) {
        finishedStrokeColor = attributes.getColor(R.styleable.ArcProgress_arc_finished_color, default_finished_color);
        unfinishedStrokeColor = attributes.getColor(R.styleable.ArcProgress_arc_unfinished_color, default_unfinished_color);

        arcAngle = attributes.getFloat(R.styleable.ArcProgress_arc_angle, default_arc_angle);
        setMax(attributes.getInt(R.styleable.ArcProgress_arc_max, default_max));
        setProgress(attributes.getInt(R.styleable.ArcProgress_arc_progress, 0));

        strokeWidth = attributes.getDimension(R.styleable.ArcProgress_arc_stroke_width, default_stroke_width);

        fuel_to_show=mMainPageFragment.carFuel;
        setProgress(fuel_to_show); //Aca puedo modificar el valor
    }

    protected void initPainters() {

        paint = new Paint();
        paint.setColor(default_unfinished_color);
        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        paint.setStrokeWidth(strokeWidth);
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        paint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
    }

   /* @Override
    public void invalidate() {
        initPainters();
        super.invalidate();
        postInvalidate();
    }*/

    public float getStrokeWidth() {
        return strokeWidth;
    }

    public void setStrokeWidth(float strokeWidth) {
        this.strokeWidth = strokeWidth;
        this.invalidate();
    }

    public int getProgress() {
        return progress;
    }

    public void setProgress(int progress) {
        this.progress = progress;
        if (this.progress > getMax()) {
            this.progress %= getMax();
        }
        invalidate();
    }

    public int getMax() {
        return max;
    }

    public void setMax(int max) {
        if (max > 0) {
            this.max = max;
            invalidate();
        }
    }

    public int getFinishedStrokeColor() {
        return finishedStrokeColor;
    }

    public void setFinishedStrokeColor(int finishedStrokeColor) {
        this.finishedStrokeColor = finishedStrokeColor;
        this.invalidate();
    }

    public int getUnfinishedStrokeColor() {
        return unfinishedStrokeColor;
    }

    public void setUnfinishedStrokeColor(int unfinishedStrokeColor) {
        this.unfinishedStrokeColor = unfinishedStrokeColor;
        this.invalidate();
    }

    public float getArcAngle() {
        return arcAngle;
    }

    public void setArcAngle(float arcAngle) {
        this.arcAngle = arcAngle;
        this.invalidate();
    }

    @Override
    protected int getSuggestedMinimumHeight() {
        return min_size;
    }

    @Override
    protected int getSuggestedMinimumWidth() {
        return min_size;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        setMeasuredDimension(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
        int width = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
        rectF.set(strokeWidth / 2f, strokeWidth / 2f, width - strokeWidth / 2f, MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec) - strokeWidth / 2f);
        float radius = width / 2f;
        float angle = (360 - arcAngle) / 2f;
        arcBottomHeight = radius * (float) (1 - Math.cos(angle / 180 * Math.PI));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        float startAngle = 90 - arcAngle / 2f; //270 for speed, 90 for fuel
        float finishedSweepAngle = progress / (float) getMax() * arcAngle;
        float finishedStartAngle = startAngle;
        if(progress == 0) finishedStartAngle = 0.01f;
        paint.setColor(unfinishedStrokeColor);
        canvas.drawArc(rectF, startAngle, arcAngle, false, paint);
        paint.setColor(finishedStrokeColor);
        canvas.drawArc(rectF, finishedStartAngle, finishedSweepAngle, false, paint);

        if(arcBottomHeight == 0) {
            float radius = getWidth() / 2f;
            float angle = (360 - arcAngle) / 2f;
            arcBottomHeight = radius * (float) (1 - Math.cos(angle / 180 * Math.PI));
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected Parcelable onSaveInstanceState() {
        final Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putParcelable(INSTANCE_STATE, super.onSaveInstanceState());
        bundle.putFloat(INSTANCE_STROKE_WIDTH, getStrokeWidth());
        bundle.putInt(instance_progress, getProgress());
        bundle.putInt(INSTANCE_MAX, getMax());
        bundle.putInt(INSTANCE_FINISHED_STROKE_COLOR, getFinishedStrokeColor());
        bundle.putInt(INSTANCE_UNFINISHED_STROKE_COLOR, getUnfinishedStrokeColor());
        bundle.putFloat(INSTANCE_ARC_ANGLE, getArcAngle());
        return bundle;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Parcelable state) {
        if(state instanceof Bundle) {
            final Bundle bundle = (Bundle) state;
            strokeWidth = bundle.getFloat(INSTANCE_STROKE_WIDTH);
            setMax(bundle.getInt(INSTANCE_MAX));
            setProgress(bundle.getInt(instance_progress));
            finishedStrokeColor = bundle.getInt(INSTANCE_FINISHED_STROKE_COLOR);
            unfinishedStrokeColor = bundle.getInt(INSTANCE_UNFINISHED_STROKE_COLOR);
            initPainters();
            super.onRestoreInstanceState(bundle.getParcelable(INSTANCE_STATE));
            return;
        }
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(state);
    }

}
```

this is inside my MainLayout, this part I want to update:

```
                    <RelativeLayout
                        android:id="@+id/scale_gaz_inmain"
                        android:layout_width="@dimen/_57sdp"
                        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/icon_gazinmain"
                        android:layout_height="@dimen/_60sdp"
                        >

                        <com.itelma.tele2.ArcProgressFuel
                            android:id="@+id/arc_progress2"
                            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:scaleX="-1"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            custom:arc_progress="50"
                            custom:arc_unfinished_color="@color/mDark_gray"
                            custom:arc_finished_color="@color/colorApp"
                            custom:arc_max="100"/>
                    </RelativeLayout>
```

so in my main java file I have:

```
 ArcProgressFuel mArcProgressFuel;


mArcProgressFuel=new ArcProgressFuel(this);
mArcProgressFuel.invalidate();
```

Comment: can you post how you are setting the progress?

Comment: @X3Btel ok, I did

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, I could resove it, with the following lines:

```
 mArcProgressFuel=new ArcProgressFuel(this);

        RelativeLayout relativeLayout2=(RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.speed_indicator);
        View child = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.fragment_speed_indicator, null);
        relativeLayout2.addView(child);
```